# Data through controller - view in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller

I have this snippet code in my Controller:

```
// load model
$this->load->model('article');
$data['article'] = $this->article->get_data_article();

// add more array in data['article']
$data['article'][] = array( 'newcontent' => 'dummy string' );

 $this->load->view('index',$data);
```

then I have 2 views, first is index.php:

```
$this->load->view('content',$article[0]);
```

second view is content.php:

```
<?php echo $title;?> <br>
<?php echo $newcontent;?>
```

I've got error on second line above. The error message is:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: newcontent
Filename: views/content.php
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to display like this,

```
echo $article[0]['newcontent'];
```

Because you have created it as a two dimensional Array.

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but no luck. The error message is the same.

Comment: just remove [] from $data['article'][] controller and put echo $article['newcontent'] in your view. Try this

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it.

```
$data['article']['article1'] = array( 'newcontent' => 'dummy string' );
$data['article']['article2'] = $this->article->get_data_article();
```

And in view

```
echo '<pre>';
print_R($article1);
echo '<pre>';
print_R($article2);
```

Now you can access. Numeric arrays cause problem passing data to views. Use indexed arrays.

EDITS :
You can pass it to view like this

```
$this->load->view('content',$data);
```

And in the view now you have $article.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_R($article);
```

if you apply php extract on article
    extract($article);
You will be able to access

```
echo '<pre>';
print_R($article1);    
echo '<pre>';
print_R($article2);
```

But the each way is to do that
Controller

```
$data['article1'] = array( 'newcontent' => 'dummy string' );
$data['article2'] = $this->article->get_data_article();
```

Pass it to view

```
$this->load->view('content',$data);
```

and access like this

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($article1);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($article2);
```

No extraction required

More EDITS:
You can do it like this

```
$result['article1'] = array( 'newcontent' => 'dummy string' );
$this->load->view('content',$result);
$result1['article2'] = $this->article->get_data_article();
$this->load->view('index',$result1);
```

Comment: Thanks but i still confuse how to pass it in index.php view, because when i change the code as you suggested, now the error is in index.php:

    Severity: Notice
    Message: Undefined offset: 0
    Filename: views/index.php

Comment: thanks again, but in controller i can't pass to "content" because my view contains 2 view (index.php and content.php and maybe more), so in controller i just pass it to "index" like this:

$this->load->view('index',$data);

then when i pass it again in view (index.php) like you suggested:

$this->load->view('content',$data);

i got error here: 

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: views/index.php

maybe my problem related with those 2 view files, about how it pass $data from and to other view?